# Servo motor analog vs digital and AC vs DC

Tags: servo

I am little confused with servo motor terminology.

Q1. AC servo motor requires AC power source ?
Q2. DC servo motor requires DC power source ?

If answer to above 2 questions are YES then what does analog servo motor means.

Q3. Can I use arduino uno to control analog RC servo motor ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q1. AC servo motor requires AC power source ? Q2. DC servo motor requires DC power source ?

Yes. It's all down to the kind of motor that is used in the servo - an AC synchronous motor (often with VFD), a small DC brushed motor (the most common RC type) or a brushless DC motor.

> Q3. Can I use arduino uno to control analog RC servo motor ?

Yes. That's precisely what the bundled `Servo.h` library is for. All the Arduino servo examples you will find online use analog RC servo motors.

The name "analog" though for those motors is not really 100% correct. They are driven by a PWM signal where the duty cycle is used to control the angle. The signal itself is 100% digital. The "analog" component comes in the form of the duty cycle of the signal.